# laravel - livewire Full-Page Components

Tags: laravel, laravel-8, laravel-livewire, livewires

I use laravel 8.

I define protected namespace in `RouteServiceProvider`:

```
protected $namespace = 'App\Http\Controllers';
```

then use livewire with the below route:

```
Route::get('/xxx' , App\Http\Livewire\Counter::class);
```

but I have the below error :

```
Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Livewire\Counter].
```

Notice: this adds `App\Http\Controllers` first of my action !!! if remove `protected $namespace` all is OK. But I do not want to delete it.

Is there a way for me to have both ‍`controller protected namespace` (for controller namespace) and a `Route::get` for `Full-Page Components`?

Comment: `Route::get('/xxx' , App\Http\Livewire\Counter::class);` to `Route::get('/xxx' , \App\Http\Livewire\Counter::class);`   before App if you put `\` theb it will consider from root level

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Unfortunately, you won't be able to use protected $namespace together with Livewire.
You'll have to comment it back out and update all your routes to the laravel 8 way: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/releases#routing-namespace-updates

Because livewire components don't live under App\Http\Controllers, using $namespace will never work.

As far as I understand it. Route::livewire existed in Livewire 1.x because of this issue in Laravel 7. But with Laravel 8 it could be removed in favor of the new way.

Answer (score 15):

For those that are still looking for a solution to this. I ran across this problem when upgrading an existing install from Laravel 7 to 8 and added some new Livewire components.

You should be able to invoke the class directly in the Route like so,

```
Route::get('/blog', [\App\Http\Livewire\Pages\ShowPosts::class, '__invoke'])->name('blogs');
```

This should allow you to use Laravels regular web routing.

Then in your Livewire component you can extend the layout like so,

```
class ShowPosts extends Component{
   ...
   public function render(){
       return view('livewire.show-posts')
        ->layout('layouts.base');
   } 
 ...}
```

[Rendering Components](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/rendering-components)

The other option is to remove the namespacing from Routes as discussed in the link below.

[Upgrading Livewire Routes](https://laravel-livewire.com/docs/2.x/upgrading#route-livewire).

Comment: Glad I could help!

Comment: This answer should be the accepted one, as it solves the problem, while Mattias's doesn't.

Comment: Thanks a lot.. it helped me with the error: **Invalid route action**

Comment: Thanks, you saved me a ton of time searching for the solution!

Comment: I can't remember how different things were in Laravel 8, but don't do it this way, it's very messy. See kodfire's answer: Just move your components into the same namespace as the other controllers and adjust the "class_name" in Livewire's config file. Then you can use all the standard Laravel syntax in your routes.php and Livewire controllers.

Answer (score 4):

In order not to modify the `RouteServiceProvider.php` file for its namespace, move `app\Http\Livewire` directory to `app\Http\Controllers\Livewire`.

Change this

```
namespace App\Http\Livewire;

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    //
}
```

to this

```
namespace App\Http\Controllers\Livewire; // <---- added Controllers

use Livewire\Component;

class Counter extends Component
{
    //
}
```

Modify `config/livewire` file from this

```
'class_namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Livewire',
```

to this

```
'class_namespace' => 'App\\Http\\Controllers\\Livewire', // <---- Controllers added
```

- Then remove what's inside `bootstrap\cache`.
- Then run `composer dumpautoload`.

After that any new livewire you make with `php artisan livewire:make`, should be modified. You should change `namespace App\Http\Livewire` to `namespace App\Http\Controllers\Livewire`.

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It means you can use the standard route syntax (correct as of Laravel 10 and Livewire 3), the artisan commands will still work and you will still keep a protected Controller namespace.

Answer (score 2):

Removed: `Route::livewire()`

Livewire 1. x allowed you to register a component with a route for the entire page using the Route::livewire() method. Livewire 2.0 now allows you to pass Livewire components directly into routes using the standard Route::get() method and the fully qualified namespace.

Before

```
Route::livewire('/post', 'show-posts');
```

After

```
Route::get('/post', \App\Http\Livewire\ShowPosts::class);
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try adding your livewire component at the beggining of `web.php`:

```
use App\Http\Livewire\Counter;
```

And in your route:

```
Route::get('/xxx', Counter::class);
```

Comment: Thanks but : Invalid route action: [App\Http\Controllers\App\Http\Livewire\Counter].